# DBus permission denied on an embedded hardware

Tags: embedded-linux, dbus, user-permissions

I'm new to DBus and I'm trying to call the following method within my own C++ application using the [sdbus-cpp](https://github.com/Kistler-Group/sdbus-cpp) library:

**org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Suspend**

The goal of the call is that the device switches to suspend mode.

The application works so far if the application runs as root user! But for security reasons I would like to run the application as a non-root user (lets say as *'embuser'*).

On the net I found out that DBus can be configure. So I put the following file in folder /etc/dbus-1/system.d/suspend.conf with this content:

```
root@colibri:/etc/dbus-1/system.d$ cat suspend.conf
<!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC
          "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Bus Configuration 1.0//EN"
          "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">
<busconfig>

  <!-- Only root or user embuser can own the login1 service -->
  <policy user="embuser">
    <allow own="org.freedesktop.login1"/>
  </policy>
  <policy user="root">
    <allow own="org.freedesktop.login1"/>
  </policy>

  <!-- Allow anyone to invoke methods on login1 server -->
  <policy context="default">
    <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.login1"/>
    <allow receive_sender="org.freedesktop.login1"/>
  </policy>
</busconfig>
```

I restarted the dbus daemon (`systemctl restart dbus`). Then, when I start my application (which is running as 'embuser') following gets printed out:

*terminate called after throwing an instance of 'sdbus::Error'
what():  [org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied] Permission denied
Aborted*

As stated above, when the application is started as root user, the application works as expected and the suspend mode gets activated. So there shouldn't be a issue with the C++ application itself.

What can I do in order to call the DBus method as non-root user? Did I miss something in the configuration file? Or what else can I do to be able to execute the DBus call?

The application is running on an embedded Linux device (Colibri module with an ARM iMX7d processor).

Here is the Linux kernel and systemd version of the embedded device:

```
$ uname -r
5.4.91-5.2.0-devel+git.c59b3c2da1e9

$ systemctl --version
systemd 244 (244.5+)
+PAM -AUDIT -SELINUX +IMA -APPARMOR -SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP -LIBCRYPTSETUP -GCRYPT -GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 -SECCOMP +BLKID -ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 -IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid
```